# What do you call someone that helps you on one hand with the intent of trying to sell you something

Tags: nouns

Example: Joe spent an hour on the phone with me helping me solve a problem, but he only did it so that afterward he could pitch me on this crappy product he wanted to sell.

Words I've considered but don't fit: scammer, snake oil salesman, frenemy.

Illustration: someone who is patting you on the back with one hand (nice, free) while reaching into your back pocket with the other to get your wallet (not nice, costly).

Comment: Why do *scammer, snake oil salesman* etc. not fit? How about *conman*?

Comment: Scammer doesn't fit because it's not a scam.  It's a legitimate sale/product/service, but it could be a bad product/service that isn't good for the customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the person a ***masquerader***

[Masquerade](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/masquerade) (Merriam Webster)

> An action or appearance that is a mere disguise or show.

Comment: That's perfect. Someone who is one thing but plays another.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with **self-serving** for the action.  In general, Joe could be said to have **ulterior motives**.